# Where do you get fur?

Tags: assassins-creed-3

A lot of people have been telling me to sell fur to get quick money.

I have been looking everywhere to get fur..... but couldn't find any.

Where do you get it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fur is called **Pelt** in game.

You get pelt by hunting and skinning animals in the Frontier. Different animals can be found in the hunting ground of the Frontier, each one giving a few different parts when skinned, that can be sold to merchants for money.

There are different way to hunt animals, either you can place loop snare and wait for an animal to be trapped, you can track them and kill them however you want (note that killing with your hands or bow provides you better quality fur), or you can be attacked by a pack of animals, you should then skin them after killing them.

As you advance in the game eventually you'll be able to buy pelts of several different animals in your homestead.

Comment: Oh, I thought fur meant the fur of an animal >.>

Comment: @Meraj99 It does. You're hunting animals to get their fur...

Comment: No, I thought fur meant like the fur of a polar bear..... the white coat-like fur o_O